# Sorting a Hash of Hashes of Array of Arrays in Perl

Tags: perl, sorting, multidimensional-array, data-structures, perl-data-structures

I made a hash (`%locus`) to organise my data, when I print it with `Data::Dumper` it shows the data structure:

```
'locus8 >9.2668516.276570.GABA3.1.54.6586237.218516.2718570 74280 74440 locus8' 
 => {    
 '3 70.75 0.995018 -1.89 -' => [          
   [                                                                           
    'window10',                                                'locus8',         
    '>9.2668516.2768570.GABA3.1.54.6586237.2718516.2718570', '74280',      
     '74400',                                                  '-',              
    '3',                                                      '120',        
    '55.87',                                                  '-17.41',         
    '-11.92',                                                 '-10.60',         
    '-1.32',                                                  '1.57',           
    '-1.58',                                                  '0.68',           
    '2.76',                                                   '0.995018'        
    ],                                                                          
    [                          
      'window11',                                                'locus8',   
      '>9.2668516.276570.GABA3.1.54.6586237.218516.2718570', '74320',          
      '74440', '-', '3', '120', '70.75', '-22.97', '-17.28', '-15.07', '-2.21', 

      '-1.89', '0.75', '1.95', '0.976184'                                       
    ]  
  ]                                                                             
  },
```

How Can I sort the internal arrays by the last element in the arrays `$_[17]`?

```
[                                                           
  [
    'window11',                                                'locus8',
    '>9.+.2668516.2768570.GABA3.1.54.6586237.2718516.2718570', '74320',
    '74440',                                                   '-',
    '3',                                                       '120',
    '70.75',                                                   '-22.97',
    '-17.28',                                                  '-15.07',
    '-2.21',                                                   '1.55',
    '-1.89',                                                   '0.75',
    '1.95',                                                    '0.976184'
  ],
  [
    'window10',                                                'locus8',
    '>9.+.2668516.2768570.GABA3.1.54.6586237.2718516.2718570', '74280',
    '74400',                                                   '-',
    '3',                                                       '120',
    '55.87',                                                   '-17.41',
    '-11.92',                                                  '-10.60',
    '-1.32',                                                   '1.57',
    '-1.58',                                                   '0.68',
    '2.76',                                                    '0.995018'
  ],
]
```

I want to maintain the data structure but, with the 'internal arrays' organised. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have to specify your requirements in more detail what you have and what you want and less in richness of your data which repels people from answering you because they can't see "big picture". Smoething like I have `{foo=>{bar=>[[1,2,3],[4,5,0]]}}` and I want `{foo=>{bar=>[[4,5,0],[1,2,3]]}}`. Do you see differnece?

Comment: You need to format the code sample in your question more appropriately - the code is mostly invisible due to side scrolling and overly deep indentation. You might try running [`perltidy`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Perl::Tidy) against it to clean things up or using the "terse" options to `Data::Dump` if you are outputting the `%locus` hash itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just try guess what you are looking for because you are not clear what you want.

```
for my $outher (values %hash) {
    for my $inner (values %$outher) {
        @$inner = sort {$a->[17] <=> $b->[17]} @$inner;
    }
}
```